# Combinatorial Optimization Matching in SQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, db2, combinatorics

I am having trouble developing a matching algorithm in SQL.  I have one table `subjects`.  Each of these needs to be matched to the same number of rows in the table `controls` (for the sake of this question let's say two rows or controls need to be selected for each subject).  The location of the selected controls must match exactly, and the controls selected should have a value in `match_field` that is as close as possible to the subjects.

Here is some sample data:

Table subjects:

```
id   location    match_field
1    1           190
2    2           2000
3    1           100
```

Table controls:

```
id   location    match_field
17    1          70
11    1          180
12    1          220
13    1          240
14    1          500
15    1          600
16    1          600
10    2          30
78    2          1840
79    2          2250
```

Here would be the optimum result from the sample data:

```
subject_id control_id  location    match_field_diff
1          12          1           30
1          13          1           50
2          78          2           160
2          79          2           250
3          17          1           30
3          11          1           80
```

It gets tricky, because, for example, control 11 is the closest match to subject 1. However, in the optimum solution control 11 is matched to subject 3.

I believe the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is close to the "correct" solution to this problem.  However, there is not an equal number of subjects and controls, nor will all controls be used (I have a few thousand subjects and a few million potential controls).

It is not necessary to obtain the absolute optimum results; a pretty good approximation would be fine with me.

It seems that there should be a nice set-based solution to this problem, but I can't think of how to do it.  Here is some code that assigns an equal number of controls to each subject based on location only:

```
select * from (
    select   subject.id, 
             control.id,
             subject.location,
             row_number() over (
                 partition by subject.location
                 order by subject.id, control.id
             ) as rn,
             count(distinct control.id)     over (
                 partition by subject.location
             ) as controls_in_loc
         from subjects
         join controls on control.location = subject.location
    )
    where mod(rn,controls_in_loc+1) = 1
```

However, I can't figure out how to add the fuzzy matching component.  I am using DB2 but can convert an algorithm into DB2 if you are using something else.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update:** I am mostly convinced that SQL is not the right tool for this job.  However, just to be sure (and because it is an interesting problem), I am offering a bounty to see if a working SQL solution is possible. It needs to be a set-based solution.  It can use iteration (looping over the same query multiple times to achieve the result) but number of iterations needs to be far less than the number of rows for a large table.  It should not loop over each element in the table or use cursors.

Comment: Why whould control 11 (180) be matched to subject 2 (2000) instead of subject 1 (190) in the optimum solution?

Comment: @Pharaoh, oops that was a typo.  Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @dan1111 . . . I would be surprised if there were an easy set-based solution.  SQL is quite deterministic.  It is hard to imagine how to tell one of the controls to be assigned to a subject that is not the closest subject.  Interesting problem, though.  Can you give a brief description of the real-world problem this is being applied to?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it is for a scientific study, creating a matched control group from a database.

Comment: I *promise* you there is no way to do this in a single `SELECT` query that uses a bounded number of subqueries! The simplest possible approach would be to look for an unweighted maximum matching in a bipartite graph, putting an edge between a subject and a control whenever their `match_field`s differ by less than some fixed threshold, and to solve even that you need *iteration*.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I wouldn't mind iteration, such as running a query repeatedly until the solution is reached.  What I am really trying to avoid is a solution that requires looping over every element.

Comment: Does the syntax need to be strictly DB2? I have no access to a DB2 installation, but I could try making something that works in SQL Server.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, an example in SQL Server or another version of SQL would be fine.  I don't mind converting an algorithm to DB2.

Comment: Why would you want the maximum flow algorithm implementation in SQL? what's the point on that?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua, well there would be some benefit to keeping all of my code for this process in SQL.  But at this point I am mainly asking out of curiosity to see if it can be done.  Even if it is not the best way of doing it, an SQL solution might be interesting and informative.

Comment: @dan1111 Do we know that we would have enough controls (i.e. `N` for each subject), or there may be situations when some subjects would not be paired to controls (or paired to fewer than `N` controls)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yes, there will be enough controls for each subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the Hungarian Algorithm is going to work, a much simpler algorithm can be used in your case. Your implicit cost matrix is a symmetric matrix of a special form:

```
ABS(SUBJ.match_field-CTRL.match_field)
```

Therefore, you can relatively easily prove that in an optimal assignment *{SUBJ<sub>i</sub>, CTRL<sub>j</sub>}* ordered by `SUBJ.match_field` the values of `CTRL.match_field` will be ordered as well.

***Proof:*** Consider an assignment *{SUBJ<sub>i</sub>, CTRL<sub>j</sub>}* ordered by `SUBJ.match_field` that is not ordered by `CTRL.match_field`. Then you have at least one *inversion*, i.e. a pair of assignments *{SUBJ<sub>i1</sub>, CTRL<sub>j1</sub>}* and *{SUBJ<sub>i2</sub>, CTRL<sub>j2</sub>}* such that

`SUBJ.match_field`<sub>i1</sub> < `SUBJ.match_field`<sub>i2</sub>, but

`CTRL.match_field`<sub>j1</sub> > `CTRL.match_field`<sub>j2</sub>

Then you can replace the inverted pair with a non-inverted one

*{SUBJ<sub>i1</sub>, CTRL<sub>j2</sub>}* and *{SUBJ<sub>i2</sub>, CTRL<sub>j1</sub>}*

of a cost that is less than or equal to the cost of the inverted assignment for all six relative placements of `SUBJ.match_field`(<sub>i1</sub>, <sub>i2</sub>) and `CTRL.match_field`(<sub>j1</sub>, <sub>j2</sub>) ([link to Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b%3Ea,B%3CA,abs%28a-A%29%2babs%28b-B%29%3E=abs%28a-B%29%2babs%28b-A%29)). ***:Proof***

With this observation in hand, it is easy to prove that the [*dynamic programming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) algorithm below comes up with the optimal assignment:

- Make `N` duplicates of each subject; order by `match_field`
- Order controls by `match_field`
- Prepare an empty array `assignments` of size `N * subject.SIZE`
- Prepare an empty 2D array `mem` of size `N * subject.SIZE` by `control.SIZE` for [*memoization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization); set all elements to `-1`
- Call `Recursive_Assign` defined in pseudocode below
- The `assignments` table now contains `N` assignments for each subject `i` at positions between `N*i`, inclusive, and `N*(i+1)`, exclusive.

---

```
FUNCTION Recursive_Assign
    // subjects contains each original subj repeated N times
    PARAM subjects : array of int[subjectLength]
    PARAM controls: array of int[controlLength]
    PARAM mem : array of int[subjectLength,controlLength]
    PARAM sp : int // current subject position
    PARAM cp : int // current control position
    PARAM assign : array of int[subjectLength]
BEGIN
    IF sp == subjects.Length THEN RETURN 0 ENDIF
    IF mem[sp, cp] > 0 THEN RETURN mem[sp, cp] ENDIF
    int res = ABS(subjects[sp] - controls[cp])
            + Recursive_Assign(subjects, controls, mem, sp + 1, cp + 1, assign)
    assign[sp] = cp
    IF cp+1+subjects.Length-sp < controls.Length THEN
        int alt = Recursive_Assign(subjects, controls, mem, sp, cp + 1, assign)
        IF alt < res THEN
            res = alt
        ELSE
            assign[sp] = cp
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
    RETURN (mem[sp, cp] = res)
END
```

---

[Here is an implementation of the above pseudocode using C# on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Wotmmc)

This algorithm is ready to be re-written as set-based in SQL. Trying to fit it into the original problem setting (with grouping by locations and making multiple copies of the subject) would add unnecessary layer of complexity to a procedure that is already rather complex, so I am going to simplify things quite a bit by using table-valued parameters of SQL Server. I am not sure if DB2 provides similar capabilities, but if it does not, you should be able to replace them with temporary tables.

The stored procedure below is a nearly direct transcription of the above pseudocode into SQL Server's syntax for stored procedures:

```
CREATE TYPE SubjTableType AS TABLE (row int, id int, match_field int)
CREATE TYPE ControlTableType AS TABLE (row int, id int, match_field int)
CREATE PROCEDURE RecAssign (
    @subjects SubjTableType READONLY
,   @controls ControlTableType READONLY
,   @sp int
,   @cp int
,   @subjCount int
,   @ctrlCount int
) AS BEGIN
    IF @sp = @subjCount BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END
    IF 1 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #MemoTable WHERE sRow=@sp AND cRow=@cp) BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT best FROM #MemoTable WHERE sRow=@sp AND cRow=@cp)
    END
    DECLARE @res int, @spNext int, @cpNext int, @prelim int, @alt int, @diff int, @sId int, @cId int
    SET @spNext = @sp + 1
    SET @cpNext = @cp + 1
    SET @sId = (SELECT id FROM @subjects WHERE row = @sp)
    SET @cId = (SELECT id FROM @controls WHERE row = @cp)
    EXEC @prelim = RecAssign @subjects=@subjects, @controls=@controls, @sp=@spNext, @cp=@cpNext, @subjCount=@subjCount, @ctrlCount=@ctrlCount
    SET @diff = ABS((SELECT match_field FROM @subjects WHERE row=@sp)-(SELECT match_field FROM @controls WHERE row=@cp))
    SET @res = @prelim + @diff
    IF 1 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #Assignments WHERE sRow=@sp) BEGIN
        UPDATE #Assignments SET cId=@cId, sId=@sId, diff=@diff WHERE sRow=@sp
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Assignments(sRow, sId, cId, diff) VALUES (@sp, @sId, @cId, @diff)
    END
    IF @cp+1+@subjCount-@sp < @ctrlCount BEGIN
        EXEC @alt = RecAssign @subjects=@subjects, @controls=@controls, @sp=@sp, @cp=@cpNext, @subjCount=@subjCount, @ctrlCount=@ctrlCount
        IF @alt < @res BEGIN
            SET @res = @alt
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
            UPDATE #Assignments SET cId=@cId, sId=@sId, diff=@diff WHERE sRow=@sp
        END
    END
    INSERT INTO #MemoTable (sRow, cRow, best) VALUES (@sp, @cp, @res)
    RETURN @res
END
```

Here is how you call this stored procedure:

```
-- The procedure uses a temporary table for memoization:
CREATE TABLE #MemoTable (sRow int, cRow int, best int)
-- The procedure returns a table with assignments:
CREATE TABLE #Assignments (sRow int, sId int, cId int, diff int)

DECLARE @subj as SubjTableType
INSERT INTO @SUBJ (row, id, match_field) SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY match_field ASC)-1 AS row, id, match_field FROM subjects
DECLARE @ctrl as ControlTableType
INSERT INTO @ctrl (row, id, match_field) SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY match_field ASC)-1 AS row, id, match_field FROM controls
DECLARE @subjCount int
SET @subjCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM subjects)
DECLARE @ctrlCount int
SET @ctrlCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM controls)
DECLARE @best int
EXEC @best = RecAssign
    @subjects=@subj
,   @controls=@ctrl
,   @sp=0
,   @cp=0
,   @subjCount=@subjCount
,   @ctrlCount=@ctrlCount
SELECT @best
SELECT sId, cId, diff FROM #Assignments
```

The call above assumes that both `subjects` and `controls` have been filtered by location, and that `N` copies of `subjects` has been inserted into the table-valued parameter (or the temp table in case of DB2) before making the call.

Here is [a running demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07cf1/12).

Comment: Great observation about the ordering property, +1. There's already a lot of work here, but I think it would be even better if you used a bottom-up DP strategy. It should be possible to calculate each "/"-shaped diagonal of the DP matrix with a single `SELECT`, as the values in each diagonal are all independent of each other, and depend only on the previous 2 diagonals. The DP matrix could thus be built up in max(nSubjects, nControls) `INSERT ... SELECT` passes.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks! I thought about using a more DP-like implementation, rather than a memoized one, but quickly realized that trying to fit a 2D array into SQL would be somewhat tricky. My SQL skills are somewhat limited, especially at writing SPs, because I never did that at work (in fact, this answer has the most complex SP that I have ever written).

Comment: Thanks for putting so much work into this problem. Your answer is definitely deserving of the bounty.  It will take some work to adapt it to DB2, but your simplification of the problem is a key insight.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at the problem and algorithm of [maximum matchings in a bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29). The idea is to build a graph where the nodes on the left are your `subjects` and the nodes on the right are the `controls` (this is why is called bipartite). Building the graph is trivial, you create a `source` node that connects to all subjects, and you connect all control nodes to a `sink` node. Then you create an edge between a `subject` and a `control` node if applicable. Then you run the maximum matching algorithm that will give you what you are looking for, the maximum possible matching of subjects and controls.

Make sure to checkout [this Boost BGL example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/example/matching_example.cpp) how to do it, you need to only build the graph and invoke the BGL function `edmonds_maximum_cardinality_matching`.

Comment: +1. If you use maximum *cardinality* (not weight) matching, you will need to decide on some threshold, and then create an edge between a subject and a control whenever their `match_field`s differ by less than the threshold.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful suggestion; it might be a good direction to explore.  What I was really hoping for, though, was some help on doing something like this in a more SQL-friendly way.  I had found other pieces of procedural code that do matching already.  Maybe it is just not possible with set-based logic, but it seems tantalizingly *like* a problem that SQL could handle.

Comment: I know the feeling, but this is a fundamentally algorithmic problem and SQL would be IMHO the wrong tool. I know this is not what you expected but at least you wont be wasting time trying to figure out ways to formulate a solution in SQL.

Comment: What you can do however, is to create a batch process in Java or C++ that reads your data, run the maximum matching algorithm and updates your tables. Good news is you get to reuse the most efficient way to compute it using BGL which is state-of-the-art in algorithms.

Comment: "Then you create an edge between a subject and a control node if applicable" This is the sticky part: could you please explain the "if applicable" thing in the context of the OP's question?