# Pairing with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, graph-theory

I'm sorry because this question is difficult.

I'm trying to find a query to pair elements between two sets.

If all combinations are allowed, the answer is quite easy as we can see in the following example :
Consider the 2 sets "In" and "Out". In "In", there are "A" and "B", and in "Out" "C" and "D".

Here is all possible combinations

```
In Out
== ==
A  C
A  D
B  C
B  D
```

A solution to pair elements is to calculate the Row_Number partition by each element and to take into account lines where row_number are equal.

```
In Out Row_numb part. by In Row_numb part. by Out
== ==  ==================== =====================
A  C   1                    1
A  D   2                    1
B  C   1                    2
B  D   2                    2
```

So the solution with equal row_number : (A-C) AND (B-D) pairing is good.

Now, I looking for a solution when only some combinations are allowed. Consider this example :

```
In Out
== ==
A  C
B  C
B  D
```

There are two pairing solutions : {(A-C),(B-D)} and {(B-C)}

My question is to find a query to retreive this solutions, and ideally the solution that maximizes the number of peers : here {(A-C),(B-D)}.

I've tried recursive CTE without success

=== Edit 1 : Answer to @Tanner

Here is the query I use.

```
select I, O
from (
        select  I, O, 
                n_i = row_number() over (partition by I order by O),
                n_o = row_number() over (partition by O order by I)
        from MyTab ) as SubQ

where n_i = n_o
```

When I play this query on the first tab with 4 lines, the resultset is :

```
I          O
---------- ----------
A          C    
B          D
```

But in on the second tab with 3 lines, I miss the pair B-D  :

```
I          O
---------- ----------
A          C
```

Comment: I don't really follow your problem, it's not clear why some combinations are allowed. perhaps add some sql to generate results to highlight the problem.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to find a maximum bipartite matching. Finding it seems to require some kind of search algorithm. Although if your number of elements is small enough, we could maybe find the solution through brute force (try all options and pick the best)

Comment: Have a read of [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858196/combinatorial-optimization-matching-in-sql).

Comment: You could use EXCEPT to exclude pairs that you want to exclude if you know them in advance.

Comment: @LondonRob Your link are very interesting. I must deepen the reading but I understand that there is no SQL query that does the work. Furthermore, do you see a way to use brute force for trying and picking the best in SQL without trigger ?

Comment: @Steve Ford This idea is intersting. We can built the cartesian product between all elements of the two set, use the query to keep line with the same row_number and make the intersection with the fisrt table. This approach doesn't give systematically the maximum matching but inside solution provided, I don't think we can find new matching unlike my query with the second tab and the lack of B-D matching.

Comment: @Polux2 I think we still need some clarification. Do you have 2 source tables (In & Out) or do you have 1 source table with 2 columns? I am also not sure what criteria you are using to exclude certain combinations.

Comment: @Steve Ford Ok, sorry for not beeing clear. I have a table with 2 columns which gives all possible matches and I need to find among these lines, those that make an entry appears only once and the same for outputs.

Comment: @Steve Ford The algorithm that I intend to use is  : 1 - List all entries, list all exits; 2 - calculate the cartesian product of these two sets; 3 - Keep only the lines whose row_number is equal; 4 - Keep only the matches that are in the initial table.